# Convex hull algorithms for sorted set of points

Tags: computational-geometry, sorting, convex-hull

I need an algorithm for computation convex hulls for sorted set of points in 3 and higher dimensions. Also I need in lower part of a convex hull and it is not necessary to construct a whole convex hull. 
Are there any efficient and quick algorithms for my purposes?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it was established by Seidel that having the points sorted does not help in terms of asymptotic time complexity, and certainly the lower half can be almost the entire hull, so that will not help either.  The randomized incremental (Clarkson and Shor) is perhaps the best choice.  Here is an applet illustration of that algorithm: [Tufts link](http://www.eecs.tufts.edu/~mhorn01/comp163/algorithm.html).

Comment: Thank you very much! Maybe I have a misunderstanding...In 2D case, when we use Graham scan algorithm and points are already sorted the algorithm takes O(n) time. Is it possible using 3D algorithm on a sorted meshgrid similarly speed up it?

Comment: @Alexey: When one says "sorted set of points in 3 and higher dimensions," the only interpretation of "sorted" that is natural is "sorted by one coordinate."  Even in 2D, "sorted by one coordinate" is not at all the same as "sorted angularly about an interior point."  And there is no equivalent in 3D of "sorted angularly." So I guess I need an explanation of what it means to you for points to be sorted in 3D.

Comment: Excuse me. It's my fault. I meant that I have a sorted grid of points, they are sorted over all coordinates. Actually, I have several functions and want to сompute a convex hull of their graphs. Does the order of points over all coordinates help to speed up the algorithm?

Comment: @Alexey: I don't believe your sorting helps, at least in terms of asymptotics.  Perhaps just using the incremental algorithm but adding the points in sorted order would be efficient...

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this hull algorithm for convex hull finding, [posted on GitHub](https://github.com/trustdigits/convexhull). This is Python and can give you results as:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

GPL C++ code for finding the convex hull of points in R3 is available at http://www.newtonapples.net/code/NewtonAppleWrapper_11Feb2016.tar.gz
The algorithm is based on sorting the points in z(x(y)) then sequentially wrapping points into a hull.
Rather appealingly the algorithm has been named after a chocolate.